# jquery dragable - remove element on drag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Using jQuery-ui I am dropping a draggable element onto a droppable element. I then turn the droppable element into a draggable element. If I then drag the new draggable element I want the element and its contents removed (deleted). I can make the droppable element draggable; however there are two issues:

1. When I drag the droppable (now draggable) element it does not delete.
2. The original element which was dragged into the droppable (now draggable) element can be dragged on its own.

[image]

In this eaxample "4WD" was dragged (cloned) into a droppable field below "Activity". The original "4WD" remains draggable (as required). The cloned "4WD" is also draggable (not wanted). The droppable field is now draggable; however, does not delete when dragged.

The code is:

```
function makeDraggable() {
    $('.dragabbleItem').draggable({
        stack: ".dragabbleItem",
        cursor: 'pointer',
        helper: 'clone',
    });
}

function makeDraggableRemove() {

    $('.dragabbleRemove').draggable({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
        }
    });
}

function makeDroppable() {
    $('.droppableItem').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'hovered',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var droppable = $(this);
            var draggable = ui.draggable;
            alert( 'The item with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!' );
            // Move draggable into droppable
            var drag = $('.droppableItem').has(ui.draggable).length ? draggable : draggable.clone().draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                stack: ".dragabbleItem",
                helper: 'clone'
              });
            drag.appendTo(droppable);
            droppable.css({top: '5px', left: '5px', background: '#B0C4DE'});
            droppable.droppable('disable');
            droppable.addClass("dragabbleRemove");
            makeDraggableRemove();
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to be to change "$(ui.draggable).remove();" to "$(this).remove();"

```
function makeDraggableRemove() {

    $('.dragabbleRemove').draggable({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).remove();           
        }
    });
}
```

Although this leaves a thick grey vertical line on the right behind. I would like that removed as well :-)